# Problem with Hash of Array

Tags: perl

Hi all
I got the problem that i cannot return the value and key in the hash of array

```
sub nextWords{
    for my $language(0 .. $#language )
    {
        my $eng = $db->selectall_arrayref("select word from words
            left outer join language
            on words.languageId = language.languageId
            where words.languageId = $language
            order by word asc
        ;"); # @language[$id] limit 10 offset $currentOffset

        #%returnArray2d = (@language[$language] =>[@$eng] );
        $returnArray2d{@language[$language]} = [@$eng];
    }
    return %returnArray2d;
}
```

I cannot really return all the list of words

```
my %newwordsList =NextWords();
    foreach my $key(keys %newwordsList)
    {
        print "here you are 2 : " . $key . "\n";
        for my $ind(0 .. @{$newwordsList{$key}}){
        print "dzo" . $newwordsList{$key}[$ind] . "\n";
    }
}

output: $key ==> 132 not 123
```

and the word cannot be printed.. it just prints some

```
ARRAY(0x320d514)
ARRAY(0x320d544)
ARRAY(0x320d574)
ARRAY(0x320d5a4)
ARRAY(0x320d5d4)
ARRAY(0x320d604)
```

Please help.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not setting up %returnArray2d correctly.

Assuming that @language contains the language ids you want, instead of:

```
$returnArray2d{ @language[$language] } = [@$eng];
```

You'll want this:

```
$returnArray2d{ $language[$language] } = [@$eng];
```

Also, you should avoid using the same name for an array and a scalar value (it works, but it's confusing) (see @language / $language in your code).

Lastly, you are correctly iterating through each key of %newwordsList, however, you will want to subtract 1 from the iteration, so that you don't go past the end of the array:

```
for my $ind ( 0 .. @{ $newwordsList{$key} } ) {
```

Should be:

```
for my $ind (0 .. @{ $newwordsList{$key} } - 1) {
```

Or (as David pointed out in the comments), you can do:

```
for my $ind ( 0 .. $#{ $newwordsList{$key} } ) {
```

Comment: Also, in your print statements, this might work better for you:

    `while (my ($language_id, $words) = each %newwordsList)
    {
        print "$language_id @$words\n";
    }`

Comment: Replace `for my $ind ( 0 .. @{ $newwordsList{$key} } ) {` with `for my $ind ( 0 .. $#{ $newwordsList{$key} } ) {` to avoid the fencepost error.